# Hibernate managed by Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Just Wants to ask that I have seen some code where Hibernate session object is manged by Spring as Auto-wiring it as SINGLETON bean. Is it good practice to do?? The object will be shared in kind of multi-user environment or Isn't better to declared it as proxy??

Comment: can you show some example where session is wired as singleton or you are confused with session factory

Answer (score 0):

A session should not be a SINGLETON bean and it should not be shared across application. In a multi-user environment, each user should have their own session instance. A widely used approach is to open a session when a request is initiated and close it when the request is completed. Spring facilitates this approach by providing a `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. If you have this filter configured, Spring will take care of session lifecycle, you just have to access it using `SessionFactoryUtils.getSession()` method. If you are using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.x, you can access the session using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.